# check script for defeating "Price-Jacking"

Tags: security, paypal, paypal-ipn

here is the fourth part of my ipn-security-ckeck.
I need you to check whether it´s secure:

```php
// Check number4 ---------------------------------------------------------
$product_id_string = $_POST['custom'];
$product_id_string = rtrim($product_id_string, ","); // remove last comma
// Explode string, make it an array; check payment !
$id_values = array();
$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_id_string);
$fullAmount = 0;
foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {

    $id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value);
    $product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0]; // Get the product ID
    $product_quantity = $id_quantity_pair[1]; // Get the quantity

    if (1 != intval($product_quantity)) {
    // Somebody is manipulating the item´s quantity
    $message = "Somebody is manipulating the item´s quantity";
    mail("me@myemail.de", "Quantity Hack", $message, "From: me@myemail.de" );
    exit()  
    }

    // remember item´s ID
    $id_values[$key] = intval($product_id);
}
    $sql = 'SELECT price FROM products WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', $id_values).')';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $fullAmount += $row["price"];
    }
$fullAmount = number_format($fullAmount, 2);
if (isset($_POST['mc_gross'])) {
    $grossAmount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
} else
    $grossAmount = 0;
    $message = "grossAmount wurde = 0 gesetzt";
    mail("me@myemail.de", "grossAmout Hack", $message, "From: my@myemail.de" );
    exit();
if ( intval($fullAmount * 100) != intval($grossAmount *100) ) {
    $message = "Possible Price Jack: " . $_POST['payment_gross'] . " != $fullAmount \n\n\n$req";
    mail("me@myemail.de", "Price Jack or Bad Programming", $message, "From: me@myemail.de" );
    exit(); // exit script
}
```

Is this a good script for defeating price-jacking?
Should i change anything?
if yes, what?
greetings and thanks

Answer (score 1):

The price should only be calculated on the server.  Why are you allowing the client to submit a price at all?  Allowing the client to submit a price allows them to try changing the price on you.  Secondly, if it doesn't agree with what you calculate on the server you throw it away anyway.  Just calculate it on the server and do not accept any price submissions from the client.

It looks like any quantity, other than 1 is considered a hacking attempt, why?

You convert product IDs into strings using

```
$id_values[$key] = intval($product_id);
```

If the client submits a non-integer value then I think this will return 0.  If you have a product ID of 0 this could cause issues.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, but how do i calculate it on the server?                                            every of my products should be sold only one time, thats why quantity must be 1.

Comment: It looks like you're already doing it with calculating `$fullAmount`.  If you can only sell one of each product why have a quantity field?

Comment: i thought, its more secured than...how do i configure it?